Adding global attributes to OpenTelemetry metrics
I am using OpenTelemetry's Metrics to get information about my environment.
I have several tenants that will use OpenTelemetry and will all be ingested into Prometheus and then Grafana.
I would like to differentiate between each one by adding some king of label/tag/attribute.
I am using the configuration below, but when I expose the /metrics endpoint using the UseOpenTelemetryPrometheusScrapingEndpoint extension method, the attribute is not shown.
    services.AddOpenTelemetry()
        .WithMetrics(opts =>
        {
            opts.ConfigureResource(resourceBuilder =>
                {
                    resourceBuilder.AddTelemetrySdk();
                    resourceBuilder.AddService(serviceName: "tenant_service_config");
                    resourceBuilder.AddAttributes(new Dictionary<string, object> { ["tenant_id"] = 2 });
                })
                .AddMeter(meters.MetricName)
                .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                .AddProcessInstrumentation()
                .AddRuntimeInstrumentation();

However, if I manually create a Metric and add a tag, it does show up in the /metrics endpoint
_userLoginCounter.Add(1, new KeyValuePair<string, object>("tenant.id", tenantId));
*** Clarification ***
I am able to get my custom metric to show up in Prometheus. What I need help with, is getting the "tenant_id" attribute/tag/label to show up in all of the built-in instrumentation (AspNetCoreInstrumentation, ProcessInstrumentation, and RuntimeInstrumentation)

Did you found any solution to this?


Check proper configuration: required OpenTelemetry, Prometheus, and ASP.NET Core packages are installed and configured right.

Add labels to each metric

Set default labels with MeterProvider


services.AddOpenTelemetryMetrics(builder =>
{
    builder.ConfigureResource(resourceBuilder =>
    {
        resourceBuilder.AddTelemetrySdk();
        resourceBuilder.AddService("tenant_service_config");
    })
    .AddMeter("YourMeterName")
    .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
    .AddProcessInstrumentation()
    .AddRuntimeInstrumentation()
    .AddPrometheusExporter(options =>
    {
        options.StartHttpListener = true;
        options.HttpListenerPrefixes = new string[] { "http://localhost:9464/" };
    });

    builder.AddView(instrument =>
    {
        return new MetricStreamConfiguration
        {
            TagKeys = new string[] { "tenant_id" },
            TagValues = new string[] { "2" }
        };
    });
});

Manually Add Labels to Metrics: If you want to add labels manually when creating a metric, you can do so like this:
var counter = meter.CreateCounter<long>("user_login_count");

counter.Add(1, new KeyValuePair<string, object>("tenant_id", 2));


When using builder.AddPrometheusExporter(options, all I have access to is:
options.ScrapeEndpointPath, options.ScrapeResponseCacheDurationMilliseconds, and options.DisableTotalNameSuffixForCounters I don't see StartHttpListener  or HttpListenerPrefixes 

Also, when using AddView, I don't have access to TagValues, only TagKeys. It appears that Views are mainly used to transform the tags that were provided (e.g. rename, drop): https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/docs/metrics/customizing-the-sdk/README.md#view

View is used to filter unwanted dimensions. It does not help with exporting tenant_id to Prometheus.

Resource is supported in PrometheusExporter, only when openmetrics format is requested. Resource is exported as target_info.
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/compatibility/prometheus_and_openmetrics.md#resource-attributes-1
Also, make sure you use somewhat new version of PrometheusExporter as it was not available in older versions : https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Prometheus.AspNetCore/CHANGELOG.md#180-rc1
